# How to move SharePoint library code to Github?

Tags: sharepoint-online, source-control

I am having the code base in my SharePoint(classic SharePoint site) library. This library having the JS,HTML,ASPX and other files and folders.(around 1000 files)

I have created one repository in Github and How I can move this code to the repository.(Example Github url: [github.xx.net](https://github.xx.net)).

After moving the code to repository if we make any changes how this will reflect in the SharePoint library ?

How I can achieve this using Visual studio professional 2022 ?

Comment: you have a client side solution with a *thousand* files?

Comment: are you envisioning a 2-way sync or just  push from github? Are you anticipating pushing this code to multiple sites/environments or just one site? Is this a classic or modern site? Are the thousand files all necessary or just the entire contents of a document library?

Comment: give a little more detail of what you're trying to do. I feel like if I spend time writing an answer it won't be useful because of some detail you've left out.

Comment: Currently we are opening the Library on OneDrive folder and making the changes in the files. So it immediately reflecting to SharePoint.

Comment: So my question is , Once we push the code to Github repo and if we want to make any changes in the existing file how it will reflect in SharePoint ? without using OneDrive.

Comment: HI Derek , I am looking for 2 way sync , I am using this code to only one site. This is a classic SharePoint site and all thousand files are needed to load the website we have developed. Aspx files are referring the js files from the library.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint libraries aren't designed to be used as code repositories. I would recommend only using services designed for storing code, such as Azure DevOps or GitHub.

Comment: that's exactly why she's asking the question

Comment: You just download the files and upload them to GitHub, it isn't hard. The last part of her question states how it would affect the library, insinuating a synchronisation between the two which isn't possible.

Comment: Or why would you do this over releasing your code via SPFx/sppkg files?

Comment: The OP is a little light with the details. SPFX would be preferred but if they have an old classic site with 1000 files then re-architecting would probably be a non-starter. A Github action running PnP Powershell or o365 CLI could totally do the syncing though.

Comment: Agreed, maybe just missing the details. Couldn't understand why anyone would be trying to achieve this otherwise

Comment: a mission critical legacy system and no one knows how it works... happens all the time